# How to verify token integrity with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-client

My architecture is a mobile app which signs in with google account, receives access token and sends it to rails application that should verify the access token integrity.

In java there is a class GoogleIdTokenVerifier which handles the verification, but in ruby I don't seem to find anything on this matter!
Google documents only signing in with rails, no token verification.

I also checked out google-id-token gem - but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This GEM might help you:   https://github.com/Nerian/google-id-token  as it appears to validate the google token you are looking for.